# What is Ruloff's theory on the origin of language?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, language

The largest recorded brain in the U.S is said to belong to one [Edward H. Rulloff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_H._Rulloff).
This guy wrote a book on his theory of the origin of languages shortly before his execution.
What was his theory? Is the book available in an online form somewhere?

Comment: [Life, trial and execution, p. 26](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433075956643&view=1up&seq=18) quotes his cranky summary:"*In languages formed upon this plan, words are not merely arbitrary signs. They are signs, each of which is specially and appropriately significant. Their significance depends upon certain artistic relations, everywhere pervading their structure. The possibility of such a structure depends upon roots susceptible of change, without loss of identity. Such roots and the mode of their manipulation are certainly unknown to the modern philologist.*"

Comment: brain 'size' has nothing to do with intelligence. You might like to read Stephen Jay Gould's 'The Mismeasure of Man'

Comment: Not the impression I got. I do not know if the manuscript is extant, if it is likely only as a physical copy in a museum or collection.

Comment: From a quick google search, I don't think the book survived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear that, whatever Ruloff's ideas about language they were actually formulated in book form - printed book or complete manuscript. Nothing appears to have been publshed under his name.

He was the subject of a book:

*Life, trial and execution of Edward H. Ruloff : the perpetrator of eight murders, numerous burglaries and other crimes; who was recently hanged at Binghamton, N.Y (1871) (Reprint) [Leatherbound]
Rulloff, Edward H. defendant. (Edward Howard), 1819-1871*,

Published by Pranava Books (2020).*

I doubt whether much if any philological reflection is to be found here but I have not been able to access the text, so can't reassure you one way or the other. I doubt if the weight of his brain is an index to the weight of his ideas, but one never knows.